# Calculus 2 Trigonometric Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

[image]

I have used the reduction formula for the integral of cos^n(x)dx but was unable to produce a correct answer. I think what throws me off is the (9x). Any helpful hints, tips, or other methods for this would be greatly appreciated. 
This was the answer I came up with through use of the formula.
[image]

Comment: First, make the substitution $ \ u = 9x \ , \ du = 9 \ dx \ . $

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick! Thanks for the help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
First use the substitution u=9x then use the another substitution cosu=z.

Comment: Thank you, the substitution of u=9x and du=9dx worked.